# Foundation's Magellan not working with fixed topbar

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation, magellan

I can't make magellan work with static topbar. There is a [Foundations Codepen](https://codepen.io/ZURBFoundation/pen/gWKLqV) example that works. This is linked to another Codepen that has a really long and messy js [here](https://codepen.io/ZURBFoundation/pen/LyejWr).

Does anyone knows how to make it work here in this [Codepen](https://codepen.io/MI5Studio/pen/MBVmNJ) without adding that long js that gives me errors. If I add my HTML to the Foundation's Codepen it works.

Have included:

```
foundation.js
foundation.core.js
foundation.min.js
foundation.magellan.js
foundation.smoothScroll.js
```

Comment: This seems to be a very old codepen (6.3.1) which includes a minified version of the Foundation JavaScript.

Comment: In my new codepen I used the latest version and is not working. This does not work anymore, only in very old versions?

Comment: any solution please?

Comment: Does anyone have a new example that works? thanks in advanced